# C# Imaginary Math Issue

Tags: c#, .net, math

Im currently developing some sort of a math problem generator. This means that i have to generate math problems and then right after evaluate those problems to get the answer for that math problem. This far im good. But my next step is to generate math problems where the answer would be imaginary numbers. For example "sqrt(-36)". Even tho i know how to evaluate math problems i don't know how to make it with imaginary numbers. So if anyone have any working libaray for this or have been into this issue before, please help. Thanks.

Comment: A library..? Seems kind of trivial to me to implement this yourself

Comment: [`System.Numerics.Complex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex.aspx) seems to have the functionality you need.

Comment: What exactly are the problems you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, if this is the thing you want/need, but the is a nice little library for complex numbers on [CodeProjekt](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3370/Complex-math-library-for-C-and-VB-NET), maybe you can adopt it to meet your requirements.

.NET 4.0 has a `Complex` class.